# PHP search shows more than one result

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to make a search for my website where if i search with member certificate no it will show his full details. But in my code when i search for Certificate No : 1 it show details of Certificate no 1, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,....

Is there any way to show single member details.

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
  $searchq  = $_POST['search'];
  $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  certificate  WHERE certificate_no LIKE '%$searchq%' ") or die ("could not search "); 
}
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count==0){   
  $output = 'There is no search result ';
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  
      $name =$row['name']; 
      $certificate_no =$row['certificate_no']; 
      $y_of_passing =$row['y_of _passing'];
      $grade =$row['grade']; 
      $score =$row['score'];

      $output.='<div>Certificate Number : '  .$certificate_no.' <div>Candidate Name :  '.$name. '<div>Grade/Score : '  .$grade.' <div>Course Name :  '.$score. '<div>Year Of Passing: '.$y_of_passing.'<div>'; 

      echo "<img src ='".$row['photo']."' height='100' width='200' >" ; 

   }

}
print("$output");
```

Comment: what is certificate_no is primerykey or unique?

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should look into MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: *"when i search for Certificate No : 1 it show details of Certificate no 1, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,."* ... well, yes, that's what you've told it to do `WHERE certificate_no LIKE '%$searchq%'` - if you want a specific cert just use `WHERE certificate_no = $searchq` ... except move it to mysqli/pdo with bound parameters; the `mysql_` extension is defunct and interpolating data into SQL like that is asking for trouble.

Comment: like is a pattern matching .That's why it's returning matched pattern result like this 10, 11,12,13,14,15,  .did you notice that the result all have that 1 . which is you used to match the pattern in like '%1' . so  you need to use comparison operator like this  certificate_no=1

Answer (score 1):

Change your query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  certificate  WHERE certificate_no LIKE '%$searchq%' ")
```

to

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  certificate  WHERE certificate_no  = ". $searchq ."
```

and try again.

**Explanation:** When you are using LIKE `'%$searchq%'` then it will search for a string having `1` at any place i.e. `PATTERN MATCHING`. But If you want equality comparison than try `=`. It will search for exact match.

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong wildcards Use either = or only like or use RLike

```
SELECT * FROM  certificate  WHERE certificate_no LIKE '$searchq'
SELECT * FROM  certificate  WHERE certificate_no = '$searchq'
SELECT * FROM  certificate  WHERE certificate_no RLike '[[:<:]]$searchq[[:>:]]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the $query like this :::

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  certificate  WHERE certificate_no LIKE $searchq ") or die ("could not search ");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Like` is a pattern matching . It will search the given string in your column.That's why it's returning matched pattern result like this `10, 11,12,13,14,15`  .Did you notice that the result all have that `1` . which is you used to match the pattern in `like '%1%'` . so  you need to use comparison operator like this  `certificate_no=1`

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.